# Set global dayJs locale at Nuxt SSR

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, dayjs

**This only doesn't work when rendered server side!**

I've got the problem, that dayJs doesn't update the locale globally after loading a page.
While i18n works fine, dayJs doesn't update there.

In fact it switches to the locale for 1 second but then **switches back to the defaultLocale set in the nuxt.config.js**.

```js
  async fetch() {
    const res = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: eventSeriesBySlug,
      variables: {
        'slug': this.$route.params.slug
      }
    });

    this.eventSeries = res.data.eventSeriesBySlug;

    // "en" or "de"
    this.locale = this.eventSeries.language.short;
    
    // i18n works
    this.$i18n.setLocale(this.locale);

    // does just update when rendered client side 
    this.$dayjs.locale(this.locale);
  }
```

I tried a watcher:

```js
 watch: {
    locale(data) {
      this.$dayjs.locale(data);
    }
  },
```

It didn't change (although the watcher is called).
It only works with setting the locale locally like:

```js
this.$dayjs(event.dateStart).locale(this.locale).format('MMM')
```

But to save this locale in a store or pass it through all components isn't really a solution I would prefer. So any ideas on this?

And again: this only happens on rendered server side. When I navigate to the page by a nuxtlink / hot reloading is happening (so client side rendering) it's fine.

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I have the very same problem in NextJS

Answer (score 0):

In **Next.js**, I wrapped dayjs into a file, then import in SSR page `@/helper/dayjs-ssr`

```js
import {
  default as _dayjs
} from "dayjs";
import "dayjs/locale/id";
import isBetween from "dayjs/plugin/isBetween";
import localizedFormat from "dayjs/plugin/localizedFormat";
import minMax from "dayjs/plugin/minMax";

_dayjs.extend(localizedFormat);
_dayjs.extend(isBetween);
_dayjs.extend(minMax);
_dayjs.locale("id");

export const dayjs = _dayjs;
export default _dayjs;
```